# What does overrideredirect() do?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have come to understand `overrideredirect` helps removing the default window decorations like the toolbar.What are its other uses? I am not very sure and couldn't find much documentation.
I am working on a mac. Using tkinter I want to obtain window which remains maxsize and cannot be resized,which i have achieved using **geometry** and **resizable**. What I need now is the guarantee that no random keystrokes by my user can close the window. Will `overrideredirect` help me in that? Is there any alternative?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [`overrideredirect()`](https://web.archive.org/web/20200731093951id_/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#Tkinter.Wm.overrideredirect-method) and set its flag to **`True`**. This will disable your window to be closed by *regular means* as mentioed in the link above. By *regular means*, it is meant the <kbd>X</kbd> button and the <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> keystrokes combination.

Since you used `geometry()` and `resizable()`, you will need to call [`update_idletasks()`](https://web.archive.org/web/20200725075330id_/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.update_idletasks-method) t*o force the display to be updated before the application next idles*.

Here is an example:

```
import Tkinter as Tk

root = Tk.Tk()
root.geometry('200x200+100+100')
root.resizable(False, False)
root.update_idletasks()
root.overrideredirect(True)
root.mainloop()
```

Drawback of this method: it always works on Microsoft Windows platform but it may not work on some Unix and MacOS platforms.

**Edit:**

You asked clarification about `update_idletasks()`, I think it is better if I quote directly from its documentation as it is clearer (but if you do not understand this quotation, please let me know):

> Some tasks in updating the display, such as resizing and redrawing
> widgets, are called idle tasks because they are usually deferred until
> the application has finished handling events and has gone back to the
> main loop to wait for new events.
>
> If you want to force the display to be updated before the application next idles, call the w.update_idletasks() method on any
> widget.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a colon (:) instead of a period (.)

root:overrideredirect(1)

should be

root.overrideredirect(1)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).