# Tkinter TTK OptionMenu won't open

Tags: unix, tkinter, python-3.6, optionmenu

***Please see my edit at the bottom, this issue is now OS specific.***

**[A gif of the problem in action](https://gfycat.com/TerrificDismalGlowworm)**

So I'm having an issue with an instance of **ttk.OptionMenu**. I've successfully implemented the widget before, however I'm trying to use it here as a dropdown for available files in a pop-up window, and I can't seem to get it to work right.

**The issue**

- Only the first option in the menu is seen, and no other options are available
- It doesn't respond to the mouse other than dimming when clicked
- When it is clicked, no errors or output are seen in the terminal, making it hard to trace

**The Code**

The actual call is made from another file, let's say `myproject/main.py`

```
from classes.load_window import *

start_load_menu()
```

The class for this is stored in a file at `myproject/classes/load_window.py`, and it accesses save files stored in `myproject/saved/`

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from os import listdir
from os.path import join, isfile

class LoadMenu(object):

    def __init__(self):
        root = self.root = tkinter.Tk()
        root.title("Save Manager")
        root.overrideredirect(True)

        """ MAIN FRAME """
        frm_1 = ttk.Frame(root)
        frm_1.pack(ipadx=2, ipady=2)

        """ MESSAGE LABEL """
        self.msg = str("Would you like to load from a save file?")
        message = ttk.Label(frm_1, text=self.msg)
        message.pack(padx=8, pady=8)

        """ INNER FRAME """
        frm_2 = ttk.Frame(frm_1)
        frm_2.pack(padx=4, pady=4)

        """ TEST IMPLEMENTAITON [DOES NOT WORK] """
        mylist = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']
        test_var = tkinter.StringVar(frm_2)
        test_var.set(mylist[3])
        test_dropdown = ttk.OptionMenu(frm_2, test_var, *mylist)
        test_dropdown.pack(padx=4, pady=4)
        print(mylist) # Results in ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']


        """ REAL IMPLEMENTATION [ALSO DOES NOT WORK] """
        files = [f for f in listdir('saved') if isfile(join('saved', f))]
        file_var = tkinter.StringVar(frm_2)
        file_var.set(files[3])
        file_dropdown = ttk.OptionMenu(frm_2, file_var, *files)
        file_dropdown.pack(padx=4, pady=4)
        print(files) # Results in ['DS_Store', 'test1', 'test2', 'test3']

        """ BUTTON FUNCTIONALITY """
        btn_1 = ttk.Button(frm_2, width=8, text="Load File")
        btn_1['command'] = self.b1_action
        btn_1.pack(side='left')

        btn_2 = ttk.Button(frm_2, width=8, text="Cancel")
        btn_2['command'] = self.b2_action
        btn_2.pack(side='left')

        btn_3 = ttk.Button(frm_2, width=8, text="Create New")
        btn_3['command'] = self.b3_action
        btn_3.pack(side='left')

        btn_2.bind('<KeyPress-Return>', func=self.b3_action)

        root.update_idletasks()

        """ Position the window """
        xp = (root.winfo_screenwidth() // 2) - (root.winfo_width() // 2)
        yp = (root.winfo_screenheight() // 2) - (root.winfo_height() // 2)
        geom = (root.winfo_width(), root.winfo_height(), xp, yp)
        root.geometry('{0}x{1}+{2}+{3}'.format(*geom))

        root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.close_mod)
        root.deiconify()


    def b1_action(self, event=None):
        print("B1")
    def b2_action(self, event=None):
        self.root.quit()
    def b3_action(self, event=None):
        print("B3")
    def nothing(self):
        print("nothing")
    def close_mod(self):
        pass
    def time_out(self):
        print ("TIMEOUT")
    def to_clip(self, event=None):
        self.root.clipboard_clear()
        self.root.clipboard_append(self.msg)

def start_load_menu():
    menu = LoadMenu()
    menu.root.mainloop()
    menu.root.destroy()
    return menu.returning
```

**Notes**

This code is based on [a response here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057672/correct-way-to-implement-a-custom-popup-tkinter-dialog-box) for a pop up window that I'm in the process of adapting for a specific purpose (the load menu).

I distilled this code to the minimum to reproduce the issue, but you can probably ignore the function definitions and window geometry.

Everything works fine other than this; the window is displayed center screen, and the button with actual functionality closes the window, it's just this odd quirk with the OptionMenu that I can't seem to find anyone else struggling with, either on here, or other forums.

In case you didn't see the link at the top, you can find a demonstration of the troublesome behavior [at this link.](https://gfycat.com/TerrificDismalGlowworm)

I'm using **Python 3.6.4** on **OSX 10.12.6**

***EDIT:***

I've since tested this code in a VM running Hydrogen Linux, [and it works fine](https://gfycat.com/GiddyCloudyAmazonparrot). My question then changes a little:

*How can I ensure that this code translates well to OSX?* Is there reading available on the discrepancies between running TKinter on different platforms?

I have found [this page](https://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/#apple-8-5-9) on the issues regarding Python, TKinter, and OSX, but even when using the recommended TCL packages with the latest stable release of Python, this issue persists.

***EDIT 2:***

Just to update, I have since found a workaround for the problem. It doesn't answer the question of the odd behavior of the OptionMenu, but I figured I would edit. Honestly, I think Listbox is probably better suited for what I wanted to do anyways. [Here it is in action.](https://gfycat.com/QuestionableSaneAngwantibo)

*Please let me know if I need to make any edits for clarity, or provide additional info. As I'm new to stackoverflow, I don't have much experience sharing issues here. Thank you!*

Comment: _Only the first option in the menu is seen, and no other options are available_  Then first print "files" to see if there is more than one item in it.

Comment: I've done that, and the list prints fine when printed normally, iterated though, and printed as *list. Even when there is only one option, I can usually still bring up the menu and see that single option come up, but even this does not happen here.

Comment: the statement _files = [f for f in listdir('saved') if isfile(join('saved', f))]_ does not return anything on my implementation of Python.

Comment: Do you have a directory called saves that has files in it when you run the program? I'm hesitant to believe that this is the issue since the list prints files present in my code, and even then, it still fails when presented with a list of numbers. I edited my post to show the results of printing the lists, as well as attaching a recording of the problem in action

Comment: You are missing a parameter to `ttk.OptionMenu` (3rd param is the default value), but that error normally results in the first option being missing, rather than being the only thing in the menu.

Comment: I've tried many combinations of parameters, including adding a default value of list[0], and still this issue persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I figured it out!**

After digging into this problem further, I distilled the code to the minimum (which I probably should have done before posting here...) and was able to pinpoint `root.overrideredirect(True)` as the offending line.

When using `overrideredirect(True)`, it's necessary to also use `update_idletasks()` before, in order to ensure that the Widget refreshes properly. While it seems Linux can still produce normal behavior without manually updating idle tasks, OS X cannot, so it becomes necessary to preface the code with

`root.update_idletasks()`

Here's a good excerpt from the documentation that I found on [*Billal BEGUERADJ's*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5906918/billal-begueradj) response on [an overrideredirect() question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38162932/what-does-overrideredirect-do)

> If you want to force the display to be updated before the application next idles, call the w.update_idletasks() method on any widget.
>
> Some tasks in updating the display, such as resizing and redrawing widgets, are called idle tasks because they are usually deferred until the application has finished handling events and has gone back to the main loop to wait for new events.
>
> If you want to force the display to be updated before the application next idles, call the w.update_idletasks() method on any widget.

While I still don't understand why exactly this widget breaks without `update_idletasks()` on OSX, I do understand now why it's good practice to use `update_idletasks()` in conjunction with `overrideredirect()` to ensure consistent behavior.

Hope this helps anyone else who may get hung up on this.

Answer (score 0):

Doing nothing other than changing "files" to a hard-coded list allows the program to run on my machine.  I can help you no further.

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from os import listdir
from os.path import join, isfile

class LoadMenu(object):

    def __init__(self):
        root = self.root = tkinter.Tk()
        root.title("Save Manager")
        root.overrideredirect(True)

        """ MAIN FRAME """
        frm_1 = ttk.Frame(root)
        frm_1.pack(ipadx=2, ipady=2)

        """ MESSAGE LABEL """
        self.msg = str("Would you like to load from a save file?")
        message = ttk.Label(frm_1, text=self.msg)
        message.pack(padx=8, pady=8)

        """ INNER FRAME """
        frm_2 = ttk.Frame(frm_1)
        frm_2.pack(padx=4, pady=4)

        """ TEST IMPLEMENTAITON [DOES NOT WORK] """
        mylist = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']
        test_var = tkinter.StringVar(frm_2)
        test_var.set(mylist[3])
        test_dropdown = ttk.OptionMenu(frm_2, test_var, *mylist)
        test_dropdown.pack(padx=4, pady=4)
        print(mylist) # Results in ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']


        """ REAL IMPLEMENTATION [ALSO DOES NOT WORK] """
        ##files = [f for f in listdir('saved') if isfile(join('saved', f))]
        files=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
        file_var = tkinter.StringVar(frm_2)
        file_var.set(files[3])
        file_dropdown = ttk.OptionMenu(frm_2, file_var, *files)
        file_dropdown.pack(padx=4, pady=4)
        print(files) # Results in ['DS_Store', 'test1', 'test2', 'test3']

        """ BUTTON FUNCTIONALITY """
        btn_1 = ttk.Button(frm_2, width=8, text="Load File")
        btn_1['command'] = self.b1_action
        btn_1.pack(side='left')

        btn_2 = ttk.Button(frm_2, width=8, text="Cancel")
        btn_2['command'] = self.b2_action
        btn_2.pack(side='left')

        btn_3 = ttk.Button(frm_2, width=8, text="Create New")
        btn_3['command'] = self.b3_action
        btn_3.pack(side='left')

        btn_2.bind('<KeyPress-Return>', func=self.b3_action)

        root.update_idletasks()

        """ Position the window """
        xp = (root.winfo_screenwidth() // 2) - (root.winfo_width() // 2)
        yp = (root.winfo_screenheight() // 2) - (root.winfo_height() // 2)
        geom = (root.winfo_width(), root.winfo_height(), xp, yp)
        root.geometry('{0}x{1}+{2}+{3}'.format(*geom))

        root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.close_mod)
        root.deiconify()


    def b1_action(self, event=None):
        print("B1")
    def b2_action(self, event=None):
        self.root.quit()
    def b3_action(self, event=None):
        print("B3")
    def nothing(self):
        print("nothing")
    def close_mod(self):
        pass
    def time_out(self):
        print ("TIMEOUT")
    def to_clip(self, event=None):
        self.root.clipboard_clear()
        self.root.clipboard_append(self.msg)

##def start_load_menu():
menu = LoadMenu()
menu.root.mainloop()
##    menu.root.destroy()
##    return menu.returning
```

Comment: Unfortunate, running your code verbatim [results in the same issue for me.](https://gfycat.com/DismalPastAsianlion) Could the issue lie in my OS' handling of python or TKinter? What platform are you running? I appreciate your help though, thank you.

Comment: I just installed a linux VM to test this, and you're correct; it works fine. Do you know why it might not be working correctly in OSX as opposed to other Unix environments?